# How to find the length of an array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, class

How can I find the length of an array of objects in C++

```
class patient
{
public:
    int id;
    char p_name[20];
    char f_name[20];
    char m_test[20];
    char c_report[20];

};
void p_detials(patient s[])
{
    char ch='y';
    int i=0;
    while(ch == 'Y' or ch == 'y')
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter Patient id : ";
        cin>>s[i].id;
        cout<<"Enter Patient Name :";
        cin>>s[i].p_name;
        cout<<"Patient's Fathers Name :";
        cin>>s[i].f_name;
        cout<<"Test of Patient :";
        cin>>s[i].m_test;
        cout<<"Pateint Report :";
        cin>>s[i].c_report;
        cout<<"\nEnter more Records (y/n) ? : ";
        cin>>ch;
        cout<<"\n";
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    pateint s[100];
    p_details(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

how can i find the length of this object array after calling p_details() function
because i want to access the array in other function for searching

Comment: Use `std::vector<patient>` instead.

Comment: Or add an argument to your function for the array length

Comment: You can't, the length must be passed in a separate parameter. Please don't shout.

Comment: You can't. Pass the size to the function or choose the C++ way. Use a std::array or std::vector.

Comment: Also note that nothing stops the user from entering a 100 character name, thus probably blowing up your program.  Use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: please DON'T YELL AT US!! Pretty please.

Comment: The C++ way would be to pass an empty vector, add rows in the function, and then just look at the size in the caller. As you are using raw arrays, you will have to revert to a C-ish way. IMHO the most common way would be for `p_details` to return the number of rows added as an int or unsigned int value.

Comment: The length of the array `s` is 100. C-style arrays don't carry size information with them. If you throw away that information there's no way to get it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to have it return the length.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

class patient
{
public:
    int id;
    char p_name[20];
    char f_name[20];
    char m_test[20];
    char c_report[20];

};
int p_detials(patient s[]) // use int instead of void
{
    char ch='y';
    int i=0;
    while(ch == 'Y' or ch == 'y')
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter Patient id : ";
        cin>>s[i].id;
        cout<<"Enter Patient Name :";
        cin>>s[i].p_name;
        cout<<"Patient's Fathers Name :";
        cin>>s[i].f_name;
        cout<<"Test of Patient :";
        cin>>s[i].m_test;
        cout<<"Pateint Report :";
        cin>>s[i].c_report;
        cout<<"\nEnter more Records (y/n) ? : ";
        cin>>ch;
        cout<<"\n";
        i++;
    }
    return i; // return the length
}

int main()
{
    pateint s[100];
    int size = p_details(s1); // receive the returned length
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `s1` declared? That's probably `s`. Ah I see. The mistake was introduced by OP.